# git: how to push to master an unrelated repo

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, push, git-push

I had a git repo on bitbucket with a project. Then I decided to completely rewrite the project from scratch. Now, I have a clean working new version of the project I would push it to bitbucked but it say to me that there are merging conflits since the two repo doesn't have a common history... I have been able to push new version to a different branch but I want that branch to be the master so that it represents the main development history. How can I push a new project to master?

Comment: Just as a warning, what you are attempting to do may possibly destroy git history, which in some cases is a Bad Idea; make sure that you will never need the code history currently being hosted before destroying it or force pushing - you won't be able to recover it later, unless you make a backup of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a remote to bitbucket called `bitbucket`, and you are on the branch you want to be pushed to master, you could force push like this:

```
git push -f bitbucket master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use git branch -m to rename the master branch to another one, then rename your different branch to master by using :

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m new-branch master
git push -f origin master
```